# Simulate keyStrokes from Android SoftKeyboard for Mobile Testing(Appium+Java)

Tags: android, appium, ui-automation, android-testing

[Input action should happen like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPnym.jpg)Mobile Automation: I have a a scenario where i have to send keystrokes(inputs) from SoftKeyboard of an android device (like inputs from a real User). I tried with KeyEvent, SendKeys, androidkeycode, adb Shell input, Keys. Everything works fine, but i do not see any character pressed from a soft keyboard. Pls, help me to get solution for this.!!

Comment: Hi. @RitzXavi, I have tried with `adb shell input keyevent 7` --> **cmd** , `TouchAction().tap(x,y)`, `driver.pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.KEYCODE_7);` , `element.sendkeys("String")`.. All the methods are working fine, but not like a real user input from softKeyboard.. :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The need: You need to simulate a press on the on-screen keyboard (using `driver.tap()`)

The problem: Cannot get the Xpath or ID's of a on screen keyboard which puts us in a difficult situation.

Since i've struggled with this same problem in the past, i will advise you to create a function that calculate where each Key is located and press on it using the coordinates.

To be more clear:

1. Get the coordinates of lowest element you can find -> the keyboard itself is below it -> we can now know the height of the keyboard.
2. get the width of the screen

now, lets say you have a total of 4 rows(first row is q,w,e..) so we will divide the height by 4.
lets say you want a key from the first row which has 10 keys total, now dived the screen width by 10.

now you need to map each key to its location in a row. After that, call this function for each key you want to press.

I understand that it's ugly, and you will struggle with it a bit, but I don't know another solution to your problem.

Comment: Thanks @David Ep for your valuable input.. lemme try it and l'll let you know how it goes...